# Error Handling: Incorrect Indention Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble with this simple code as it is giving me an error stating that there is an incorrect Indention.

```hs
    opMe x y op = if op =="+" let x+y
    
    main=do
      op = "+"
      x = 8
      y = 10
      print(opMe (x, y, op))
```

The return I am looking for is 18.
The return I have received is Incorrect Indention.

Comment: looks like some strange indentation on your top line. You'll also get parse errors for `main` when you fix that, if you want to assign to a variable inside a `do` block you must precede it with `let`. (And I encourage you to learn the basics of Haskell: [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) is the best starting point.}

Answer (score 2):

Lots of problems here. Let's fix them one by one:

```
 opMe x y op = if op =="+" let x+y

main=do
  op = "+"
  x = 8
  y = 10
  print(opMe (x, y, op))
```

```
q58566673.hs:3:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
  |
3 | main=do
  | ^
```

The problem here isn't actually indentation. It's that your `if` statement doesn't have a `then` or `else`, so the parser is expecting it to continue, rather than you starting a new declaration. It looks like you used `let` where you meant to use `then`, so let's change that. Also, `else` is mandatory in Haskell. Since you didn't define any other operations yet, I'll use `undefined` for now, which will let your program compile, but crash if you ever end up there.

```
 opMe x y op = if op =="+" then x+y else undefined

main=do
  op = "+"
  x = 8
  y = 10
  print(opMe (x, y, op))
```

```
q58566673.hs:3:1: error: parse error on input ‘main’
  |
3 | main=do
  | ^^^^
```

Still doesn't work. Ironically, now the problem is indentation, but the new error message no longer mentions that as a possibility. Specifically, the problem is the leading space before `opMe`. Let's remove that.

```
opMe x y op = if op =="+" then x+y else undefined

main=do
  op = "+"
  x = 8
  y = 10
  print(opMe (x, y, op))
```

```
q58566673.hs:4:6: error:
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
  |
4 |   op = "+"
  |      ^
```

Here, GHC's suggestion is correct. You need to use `let` to declare variables in a `do` block.

```
opMe x y op = if op =="+" then x+y else undefined

main=do
  let op = "+"
  let x = 8
  let y = 10
  print(opMe (x, y, op))
```

```
q58566673.hs:5:11: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘8’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include x :: a0 (bound at q58566673.hs:5:7)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: 8
      In an equation for ‘x’: x = 8
      In the expression:
        do let op = "+"
           let x = 8
           let y = 10
           print (opMe (x, y, op))
  |
5 |   let x = 8
  |           ^

q58566673.hs:6:11: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘b0’ arising from the literal ‘10’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num b0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include y :: b0 (bound at q58566673.hs:6:7)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘b0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: 10
      In an equation for ‘y’: y = 10
      In the expression:
        do let op = "+"
           let x = 8
           let y = 10
           print (opMe (x, y, op))
  |
6 |   let y = 10
  |           ^^

q58566673.hs:7:3: error:
    • No instance for (Show
                         ((a0, b0, [Char]) -> [Char] -> (a0, b0, [Char])))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (opMe (x, y, op))
      In the expression:
        do let op = "+"
           let x = 8
           let y = 10
           print (opMe (x, y, op))
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do let op = ...
                 let x = ...
                 let y = ...
                 ....
  |
7 |   print(opMe (x, y, op))
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

q58566673.hs:7:9: error:
    • No instance for (Num (a0, b0, [Char]))
        arising from a use of ‘opMe’
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(opMe (x, y, op))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (opMe (x, y, op))
      In the expression:
        do let op = "+"
           let x = 8
           let y = 10
           print (opMe (x, y, op))
  |
7 |   print(opMe (x, y, op))
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's a spectacularly unhelpful set of error messages. The reason these errors are so unhelpful is that they're a type mismatch error, but you didn't specify a type for `opMe`, so GHC inferred one that was more polymorphic (and thus gives more complicated error messages) than necessary. Let's add a type signature to get a better error message.

```
opMe :: Integer -> Integer -> String -> Integer
opMe x y op = if op =="+" then x+y else undefined

main=do
  let op = "+"
  let x = 8
  let y = 10
  print(opMe (x, y, op))
```

```
q58566673.hs:8:14: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’
                  with actual type ‘(Integer, Integer, [Char])’
    • In the first argument of ‘opMe’, namely ‘(x, y, op)’
      In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(opMe (x, y, op))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (opMe (x, y, op))
  |
8 |   print(opMe (x, y, op))
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Much more clear. The problem here is that you defined your function curried (i.e., `opMe x y op`), but then called it as if it were uncurried (i.e., `opMe (x, y, op)`). To fix it, pick one or the other and stick to it. Since currying is idiomatic in Haskell, let's go with it:

```
opMe :: Integer -> Integer -> String -> Integer
opMe x y op = if op =="+" then x+y else undefined

main=do
  let op = "+"
  let x = 8
  let y = 10
  print(opMe x y op)
```

```
18
```

And we're done! It works now.